# Why is an arrow pointing through a glass of water only flipped vertically but not horizontally?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, geometric-optics, lenses

Look at the bottom picture for example. If I try to imagine the glass of water as a lens, shouldn't it be flipped in both axes? Why does it only flip in one axis?

[image: 1]

Comment: That arrow is flipped horizontally, not vertically (although it is flipped about a vertical axis).

Answer (score 28):

Because it is a cylinder, which is a lens, along one axis, and homogeneous along the other. :)

As in @fectin's comment: if it were a *sphere*, rather than a cylinder, then it would flip through the central axis (as more-typical convex lenses do).

Comment: OP should repeat the experiment with a goldfish bowl. :)

Comment: So this is not equivalent to looking in a mirror and seeing the image 'flipped' horizontally and not vertically? :)

Comment: @matt_rule :) :)

Comment: @matt_rule a mirror doesn't actually flip horizontally *or* vertically. A mirror flips depth-wise.

Comment: In case people are puzzling over @SimonLundberg 's comment, notice that when you compare yourself with your image in a full length mirror, your right hand acquires the orientation of a left hand, but stays on the same side of your body

Comment: "a cylinder not a sphere" might be clearer?

Comment: Teachers of small children often mix up their own left and right. The problem is that, when they mimic an action like "raise your right hand" while facing the class, they have to raise their own *left* hand.